# .Net Language Interoperability Gotchas

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I hope this is the appropriate forum to ask this question.

A group of colleagues and I just starting learning C# a few weeks ago and we are planning on having a discussion about language interoperability.

So, I am looking for known/classical examples of .Net language interoperability issues. Like this one, where the case-insensitiveness of VB.Net makes an overloaded C# method incompatible.

**In C#**

```
public class Foo
{
    public void foo() { }
    public void fOO() { }
}
```

**In VB.Net**

```
Public Class Bar
   Sub Bar()
      Dim foo As Foo
      foo = New Foo()
      foo.foo(); //compiler error
   End Sub
End Class
```

Or this one in which a VB.Net keyword is used in a C# method name:

**In C#**

```
public class Foo
{
   public virtual void Stop() { }
}
```

**In VB.Net**

```
Public Class Bar
    Inherits Foo

    Public Overrides Sub Stop() 'compiler error
    End Sub

End Class
```

I would love to gather a few more examples of this type of issues.

Does anyone know any other interesting cases of language interoperability gotchas?

I used C# and VB.Net in these examples, but any .Net language interoperability issue will be just as good to enrich a discussion on the subject.

Comment: is it the same post? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691538/net-language-interoperability-gotchas

Comment: @ElYusubov Yes, in Stackoverflow it was suggested to me that this question should belong in this forum, and not in SO. I waited till it was closed to reopen it here. Is there a reason why it should not belong here?

Comment: OK, no problem. juts wanted to verify. Thx!

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the second example you posted can easily be handled by placing brackets around the keyword, like so: `Public Overrides Sub [Stop]()`

Comment: @Bryan Ross but then you have to include the brackets each time the function is called, right?

Comment: Technically, yes. But then again these are the kinds problems that are unavoidable whenever you are crossing the language boundary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Common Language Specification is a key

It would be better to enhance your understanding of how to write a Common Language Specification (CLS) compliant code. I believe that would resolve most of the issues that you have faced or found.

Basically, CLS compliance refers to CLS rules and restrictions that being followed. However, the concept has a more specific meaning depending on whether you are describing CLS-compliant code or CLS-compliant development tools, such as a compiler. CLS-compliant tools can help you write CLS-compliant code.

[image]

There are numerous articles on MSDN and elsewhere that I would suggest to follow:

- [Cross-Language Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2c7tshk.aspx)
- [Handling Language Interoperability with the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973862.aspx)
- [Writing CLS-Compliant Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx)
- [Language Interoperability](http://www.ignani.com/Blog/Article/tabid/74/Article/69/c-40-ch01c-language-interoperability.aspx)

Comment: IIRC FxCop has rules to help here

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that you are not restricted in the code that is internal to your assembly, only things that are exposed publicly need to be CLS compliant.

- Don't expose unsigned variables.
- Don't expose identifiers that only differ by case.
- Operator overloading, some languages can't use overloaded operators, so provide a method to achieve the same function as your overloaded operator.
- Avoid unmanaged pointers.
- Keep names unique, for example don't name a types method and field the same thing.
- Don't expose boxed value types.
- Don't overload fields or events.
- Don't overload properties by type.
- Don't overload methods by return type.
- Expose alternative methods for implicit and explicit casts.
- Don't expose variable length argument lists (params keyword in C#).
- Don't use arrays with a nonzero lower bound (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5733008/279999).
- Don't throw objects that don't inherit from System.Exception.
- Mark your assembly with ([System.ClsCompliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute.aspx)) attribute.